# expand polygons in scene so all faces are isolated?

Tags: scene, select

I would like to know if it is possible to **expand all faces on an object in the viewport to make it easy to identify and select specific vertices on a face**. The best description I can come up with is to 'expand' all faces on an object so I can select a face easily, or a vertex **in a viewport context**.

My model is imported geometry so I don't know what is welded or not, I am hoping each triangle is imported as its own face and vertex set.

I do not want to edit the model to expand it via a modifier, **I want to know if Blender supports a render mode that does this expansion thing so it's possible to view all faces in isolation, like I have shown in the attached graphic, and what that command is**.  The graphic shows a standard view and an 'expanded view' of the same model in a different 3D editor.

Please see the attached image, captured from other 3d app.[image: example of standard, expanded model views]

Is there a way to do this in blender??  This is a temporary thing for selecting, like a display mode shift etc. not an edit to the model.

Thx

Comment: are you trying to split the faces? Mesh > Split > Faces by Edges. Then you can scale down each face if you enable the Transforme Pivot Point > Individual Origins. But the faces are now splitted  ;)   you can still join them back if you scale them up a bit and M > Merge by Distance

Comment: hmm.. no.  What I am looking for is a temporary change to the scene in the viewport, not actually to edit the model.  I would think this could be a display model function if it exists.

Comment: do you want to select a vertex/edge/link and then press L to have all linked? honestly....we are guessing here because your description isn't really good and i assume your question will soon be closed if you don't improve your question so that it is clear, what you mean....

Comment: Seriously?  Even though I say exactly what I want to do, and illustrate the question, you think it's vague?  Wow.  You did read the question and my follow-up comment right? Presumably this is not a Blender function, so I will need to find some other way to get at it.  I could isolate the face in order to select a vert, but that really seems like more work than it should/could be.

Comment: Are you trying to do pre-selection highlighting, or perhaps trying to select faces from centers? "Expand" is not really a clarifying description of those blue lines. Do you want edges drawn thicker so they can be selected more easily?

Comment: What you are calling blue lines is the background showing because the model faces have all been ?shrunk or ?expanded, ties directly to my question.  I guess since the question has been closed I was too obtuse about saying I wanted to select a vertex on the imported model on a particular face.  Thinking about moderating my response to Chris I figured out an alternative path, it's just (slightly) more work than that other 3D app.

Comment: Please edit your question (if you want an answer), absolutely unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: According to a dictionary, *to expand* is to become or make larger. On the second image, the triangles become smaller, not larger: https://imgur.com/ndUA6Ps . So this is one reason why we're confused, another is that you want it for selection to be easier, and yet decreasing triangles like that in my opinion makes selection harder. If there are "doubles", i.e. more than one vertex in the same place, a mode like that indeed would help selecting a particular vertex, and mentioning it in the question would clear up what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Let's say there are 2 faces, which share 2 vertices: https://i.imgur.com/IdmnxkV.png - do you want them to be *"expanded"*, so there's a space between them, and selecting a shared vertex, e.g. `1` would be displayed as selecting both bottom-left vertex of the right face, and bottom-right vertex of the left face? Or would you rather have such connected faces to not be moved apart, therefore clearly displaying which faces are connected into so-called *"islands"*? Or do you just want to work under an assumption, that all faces are separate and ask for a tool that works under such assumption?

Comment: "do you want them to be "expanded", so there's a space between them, and selecting a shared vertex, e.g. 1 would be displayed as selecting both bottom-left vertex of the right face, and bottom-right vertex of the left face?"  - Yes, nailed it.  I don't know that I care if verts are shared, just they are no longer occupying the same screen space so I can choose which one to grab.